# No Module named 'initExample' in pyqtgraph directory

Tags: python

I am doing a project which involves getting around 20 readings from a GPIO pin and then plotting them on a graph, which needs to happen continuously as fast as possible. The pyqtgraph directory seems really good and fast but I am coming across an error. I downloaded pyqtgraph-0.10.0 and placed the extracted folder on the desktop. The .py files in the examples folder work fine but do not work if I use that code outside of the folder.

According to their readme file, I used

```
cd /home/pi/Desktop/pyqtgraph-0.10.0
```

and then used `python setup.py install`

I even installed Pyside, PyQt5 and PyQT4 seperately, but whatever I seem to do I get the same error:

```
import initExample
ImportError: No Module named 'initExample'
```

Any error in what I am doing? Any help will be greatly appreciated.